# Send me your email ID, I will fix it for you

Tags: discussion

> I don't want to see from my third eye, but I am forced to sometime.

I have seen these few times that users asking for personal email ID in order to fix the issue. For ex: [How to display Shop by options before the product details/ items in mobile view only?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126273/how-to-display-shop-by-options-before-the-product-details-items-in-mobile-view)

[image]

I see above scenario as violation of SE's policy (wait I haven't checked SE's policy). At least it is not ethical for me to ask for email address. I can sense of some fishy going on there. I wouldn't recommend providing email ID or any other personal info publicly though.

I might be wrong totally. Pardon me if I am offending some of you. This is just my opinion.

**Question**

Can I flag these comments? OR simply should I ignore them.

Comment: Wow, this user is coming from the future, he has experience with Magento 5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is certainly not good for our <del>forum</del> Q&A. Such comments should be flagged immediately so that moderators can take necessary actions against this.

Please flag all such users immediately without any mercy.

Comment: "without any mercy" is kind of harsh, don't you think? Just flag the Q and let the mods deal with it.

Comment: @philwinkle i don't think it's harsh. i said do flagging without mercy or without a double thought. Oh may be in your country/region, it may sounds harsh. #LanguageBarrier. English is not my mother tongue lang. :)

Comment: It defeats the point of the forum. Is everyone who has the same issues supposed to email this guy for years down the line hoping he will answer?

Reporting it immediately without a thought is the correct action, the action that happens afterwards can be where the though process kicks in.

Comment: Well, you don't flag users. You flag comments or posts that they make. After a while if a user continues to exhibits a certain behaviour pattern they may be [warned and/or suspended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1336/243324)